# Offering an SSL certificate through HttpServlet or similar

Tags: jakarta-ee, ssl, jetty

The setup: I have a Jetty (8.1.5 if it matters) Server running a simple site over https, using a self-signed certificate (it's intra-net so this is not an issue). This works.

However, in order to provide a better user experience I would like to serve up the SSL certificate for download and installation, with the correct content-type "application/x-x509-ca-cert". In order to do this I need two things:

1. A way to obtain the certificate from the KeyStore that Jetty uses. I know I can do this using the OpenSSL client, but I really need to do this programmatically, and preferably without having to open a new connection to the server.
2. A way to offer this certificate to the user in the correct format. I'm pretty convinced I can do this by writing a custom HttpServlet to do this, but is there a smarter/quicker way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a bit of code that would validate certificates of signed jars a while back, you can probably use it for inspiration for a servlet that could have a reference to a keystore and return certs.  It might help you get started at least.

https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-webapp-verifier/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/verifier/rules/JarSignatureRule.java

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in the past which could be another option for you to consider:

1. Download Server certificate (don't need openSSL) using just your browser.  Access your web site, view the certificate and copy/export the certificate to your computer.
2. Copy that server certificate to your web server and publish an HTTP page on your Jetty with link to download that certificate and instructions to install in different browsers (preferrably with screenshots).
3. Share this link with users who will access your (HTTPS) web site

Comment: Thanks, but I really needed a solution that worked with the Java KeyStore (as that's what Jetty uses). Sorry if I wasn't too clear on that.